# How to update element style on click with ng-style

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, ng-style

I need to update the size of a div when I click on a specific button.

This is the code for resizing the div

```
   $scope.ResizeBand = function(dashboard)
            {
                StateToUpdate(dashboard);
                dashboard.Height = dashboard.Height + DashboardHeightIncrease;
            };
```

When I use the code below in my template, everything works as expected

```
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-{{widgetitem.ColumnWidth}}"  style="height:{{dashboard.Height}}">
```

unfortunately, this doesn't work in IE (11), and it's recommanded to use the ng-style attribute.
So I changed

```
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-{{widgetitem.ColumnWidth}}" ng-style="{'height':'{{dashboard.Height}}' + 'px'}">
```

But when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this(work for me in ie11)

html:

```
ng-style="calculateCircuitGroup(circuit.numberOfPoles)"
```

controller

```
$scope.calculateCircuitGroup : function(numberOfPoles) {
    return {
        width  : (numberOfPoles * CIRCUIT_WIDTH) + 'px'
           }
},
```

Comment: This code works (it changes the property of the height) but visual isn't there any difference (so the div won't resize)

Comment: @PJDW , maybe you create example in plunker?

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed Angular syntax (`{{ ... }}`) inside a `class` element...
You should use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) ...

And note that using `'{{dashboard.Height}}'` (Angular syntax *inside* quotes) will *not* be evaluated by Angular, but left as-is...

Comment: Sometimes, i need a calculation like this : {{dashboard.Height-(widgetitem.NumberOfRows * 10)}} so  I think I need these brackets on that moment

Comment: I see... I mean: I suppose it won't work as you expect... :-(

Answer (score 0):

DId you try

```
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-{{widgetitem.ColumnWidth}}" 
            ng-style="{'height': dashboard.Height+'px'}">
```

(without brackets at all)?